# Prevent mat-menu close on form input focus

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a feedback form inside a mat-menu that looks like this:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before" class="filter-menu" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
      <div>
          <form [formGroup]="feedbackForm" (submit)="submitFeedback()">
              <div class="form__wrapper mt-4">
                  <div class="flex">
                         <div>
                            <label for="email" class="form__label">Email</label>
                             <input type="email" name="email" disabled 
placeholder="{{email}}" id="">
                          </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                       <label for="feedback" class="form__label">Feedback</label>
                         <textarea placeholder="Your feedback" formControlName="feedback" rows="4" name="feedback"></textarea>
                  </div>
                    <button class="btn" type="submit">Send Message</button>
               </div>
           </form>
    </div>
</mat-menu>
```

I added `$event.stopPropagation();` to prevent the menu from closing when I click inside it but it still closes when I focus on the textarea. Any help on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event.stopPropagation() needs to be in the function triggered by the focus event on the input field being focused on.

You need to pass the event when the `(focus)="myFunc($event)` and then in the `myFunc(event) { event.stopPropagation() }`.

This should work :)

Comment: It does. Thanks!

Comment: other way is put the event.stopPropagation in the inner div: `<mat-menu #menu="matMenu"...><div (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">...</div></mat-menu>`